# Handle click and swipe in PyGTK

Tags: python, swipe, pygtk

I am trying to figure out how to handle swipe events on an image using PyGTK.
I am currently using a BUTTON_PRESS_MASK to get a button press event on the image and printing out the coordinates.

I'd like to be able to also print out swipe events (beginning coords ,end coords) as well as handle single button presses.

The way I'm handling button presses:

```
self.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
self.connect('button-press-event', self.on_screen_click)

def on_screen_click(self, window, event):
    assert event.type == gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS
    print('{}, {}'.format(event.x, event.y))
```

Anyone have any suggestions?  My first thought was to handle a BUTTON_RELEASE event, but I'd have to save x/y from BUTTON_PRESS and somehow figure out it isn't a single click so as not to execute my on_screen_click code.

Comment: Wow, you're *actually* using pygtk. I was about to remove the tag out of habit...

Comment: Do you have a really good reason for pygtk instead of Gtk3 + GObjectIntrospection?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with using Gtk3 + GObjectIntrospection.  If I switched to that, could I handle swipe easier?